# Display JSON data in php

Tags: php, json

From a SDK my json data appears like :

```
$count_categories_json = "{\"api\":
{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"cal_url\":\"http:\/\/www.example.com\",\"encoding\":\"ISO-8859-1\",\"generated\":\"2014-01-20T17:23:21+01:00\",\"contents\":\"categories_event_count\"}
,\"0\":{\"id\":\"47\",\"name\":\"Expositions\",\"parent_id\":\"0\",\"event_count\":\"679\",\"rank\":1}
,\"1\":{\"id\":\"94\",\"name\":\"Gratuit\",\"parent_id\":\"56\",\"event_count\":\"598\",\"rank\":2}
…}
```

with code below it displays

> events -
>
> 679 events - Expositions
>
> 598 events - Gratuit

```
$array = json_decode($count_categories_json,true);

    foreach ($array as $jsons) {
        echo '<li>'.$jsonsc3['event_count'].' events - '.$jsonsc3['name'].'</li>';
    }
```

First lign is of course non desired and comes from first element of json ("api":{\"version\":\"1.0\",\ ...)

Question is : how to don't dispay it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($count_categories_json,true);

array_shift($array);

foreach...
```

[`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/array_shift) will remove the first array element.

Answer (score 0):

Before your `foreach`, add the following:

```
unset($array['api']);
```

This will remove the 'api' property from your JSON object.

Alternatively, insdie the `foreach` loop, add:

```
if ( !isset($jsons['id']) ) continue;
```

This will skip every line that does not have an "id" property defined.